# How am I seeing two different versions of the app based on two branches that work off of eachother?

Tags: git, github

There are two branches, `master` and `develop`.  `master` is what the world sees, `develop` is supposed to be a copy of `master` so we cut branches off of `develop` and push up our work into `develop`.

My lead pushes a branch onto `develop` called `versionB` with work.  I proceed to pull `versionB` off of `develop` and I see the latest and greatest build of our app and the correct one to work off of.

Here's my question and the part I don't get:  If I only check into `develop`, I see the previous version (let's call it `versionA`) of our app and not `versionB`.

How's that possible if `versionB` was pulled from `develop`?

I checked out to `master` and ran `git pull` only to see that `versionB` is indeed on `master` like it should be.

But how come when I check into `develop`, I see `versionA` of the app?  I can't see how this is possible.  My apologies if this seems kind of confusing :(.

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your commit graph? I'm having a hard time visualising it based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

As Dai mentioned, it would be more convenient if you can post a diagram of your problem. From what I could decipher, below is my interpretation.
Let me know if it is right or not.

```
Master       Develop      versionB
   A           A
   |           | 
   B           B ---------- B'
   |           |            |
   C           C(versionA)  C'
   |                        |
   D(latest Build)          D'(latest Build)
```

As per the description you gave, it means that versionB is a branch that your lead has pushed on to develop.
As per the diagram I made, it means that versionB branch was directly merged on to master. So master has the latest changes and so does versionB. Probably Develop branch is not running identical to master.

One quick note, in the above diagram B' must have been rebased to C of develop branch.

Rebased:

```
 Master       Develop      versionB
   A           A
   |           | 
   B           B            
   |           |            
   C           C(versionA)--B'
   |                        |
   D(latest Build)          C'
                            |
                            D' (latest build)
```

If this is not what you meant, can you please make a better diagram and give a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: this actually makes sense!  I came to the same conclusion yesterday via tracing history & it seems like you've verified for me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! If you've figured out the solution, can you please mark this post as answered? This way others won't require to make an effort from scratch again. Thanks!